# C# MS Unit test call a method before validating Data source details

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I've a unit test function with `[DataSource("ConnectionStringName")]` and custom attribute function and a `[ClassInitialize]` decorated method which will execute before actual test method runs.

In `[ClassInitialize]` decorated method I'm adding data source connection string of different types in the configuration file based on my custom attribute.

The problem is before calling `[ClassInitialize]` method my unit test function verifying the connection string name `ConnectionStringName` is available in the configuration or not and thus giving exception like

> **'Data source 'ConnectionStringName' cannot be found in the test configuration settings'**

before calling `[ClassInitialize]` decorated method, which is failing to update the connection string in configuration file.

Any trick to make a call to the `[ClassInitialize]` decorated method, even connection string was not found in the configuration settings for any test method.

Below is my code.

```cs
[ClassInitialize]
public static void TestSetup(TestContext context)
{
    DataSourceConnectionHelper sourceConnectionHelper = new DataSourceConnectionHelper(typeof(AccountControllerTest), context.FullyQualifiedTestClassName, context.TestName);
    var status = sourceConnectionHelper.UpdateConnection();
}

[CsvDataConnection(@"DataSource\UserData.csv")]
[DataSource("ConnectionStringName")]
[TestMethod]        
public void UserValidationTest()
{
}
```

Comment: that's not a unit test. you're talking about connection strings and verifying configurations, you're already on the wrong path. In a unit test you abstract such things away.

Comment: May be I explained bad or you totally misunderstood my idea here. The thing is I'm eliminating some steps while defining data source by creating data source connection strings dynamically and writing them into configuration file based on the custom attribute type defined (here CsvDataConnection or ExcelDataConnection etc..), so that every time I no need to define 'provider name', 'DataAccessMethodType', etc...